# How to create a PDF file through the VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation, vb.net-2010

Here i use vs 2010 and install Adobe Reader 11.0 in system. I tried something like-

```
Private Sub OpenButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenButton.Click

    Dim open1 As FileDialog
    Dim inFileName As String
    Dim outFileName As String
    Dim i As Long
    open1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    """
    "'"""
    ""       
End Sub
```

Comment: Use Itextsharp Library for Create Pdf.

Comment: I don't think *Adobe Reader* allows you to *generate* PDF files. It's a **reader** for a reason.

Comment: I don't see the part where you actually tried.

Comment: Hopefully post #2 will go better...

Comment: @Neolisk and anakata . Ok Friends ,simply i try to create *.pdf file in vb.net. Adobe_Reader is not a matter.Or any _file is open in pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you actually want to print; for Excel (old versions) I usually print to postscript printer driver; then use [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) command line to convert from PS to PDF.

You need to have the GhostScript files. Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
    Dim PSPrinterSetupName As String
    Dim svPsFileName As String
    Dim svPDFName As String


Sub testRun()
    'set up a printer using driver "HP C LaserJet 4500-PS" or something similar
    'name it "PostScript Writer"
    'set it to "print to file"

    'set the name of the printer to use
    PSPrinterSetupName = "PostScript Writer"

    'set the postscript file name (must be 8.3 notation;
    'no long names; no spaces; you can move and rename the file later)
    svPsFileName = "C:\Temp\input1.ps"

    'set the PDF name (must be 8.3 notation;
    'no long names; no spaces; you can move and rename the file later)
    svPDFName = "C:\Temp\Output1.PDF"

    Call printToPS
    Call ConvertToPDF
End Sub

Sub printToPS()
    Dim PrinterInUse As String
    PrinterInUse = Application.ActivePrinter
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut ActivePrinter:=PSPrinterSetupName, PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=svPsFileName
    Application.ActivePrinter = PrinterInUse
End Sub

Sub ConvertToPDF()
    Dim fso
    Dim lcCmd As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    lcCmd = "C:\Progra~1\GS\Misc\GhostS~1\GSWIN32C.EXE " & _
    "-q -dNOPAUSE -IC:\Progra~1\GS\Misc\GhostS~1\lib;./fonts " & _
    "-sFONTPATH=./fonts -sFONTMAP=C:\Progra~1\GS\Misc\GhostS~1\lib\FONTMAP.GS " & _
    "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=" & svPDFName & " -dBATCH " & svPsFileName
    Shell (lcCmd)

End Sub
```